# Selenium : Not able to click on WebElement

Tags: java, html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium,

**HTML snippet**

```
<a class="board-icons" href="/htw/qmsHtwDoc/newRegQueries">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is, I am not able to click on specific element, I have used following locators to perform an action but nothing worked!! [Not showing any error it's just skipping that line in the scripts instead of clicking on that Particular element]

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-file-text-o")).click();
```

(or)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/div/div/a/i")).click();
```

(or)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sub-container']/div/div/div/a/i")).click();
```

So far I Used action class as well But did not worked.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sub-container']/div/div/div/a/i"));
actions.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
ele.click();
```

Please help with this issue

Comment: If the class name is unique try clicking using class name. Without using xpath or css selector

driver.findElement(By.classname("fa-file-text-o")).click();

Comment: it will be better if u will post the full source form the div,also please mention  webelemnt on whcih you are clicking is of what type (e.g button ,link ....).Also if its not showing any error then it must be clicking at some where on the screen

Comment: use cssSelector like this:       "a.board-icons > i.fa.fa-file-text-o"

Comment: what is the error you are getting in console

Comment: earlier i have used unique class name as well even though dint worked for me!! @VarunBajpai

Comment: Can you try with xpath:  //div[@id='sub-container']//a[@class='board-icons']

Comment: @Bhoomi - there is no other element with same class name? possibly it would be clicking on some other element with same classname? was there any error when you tried? is this happening on any particular browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath :-

```
//div[@id='sub-container']//a[@class='board-icons']/i[@class='fa fa-file-text-o']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Get back to me if you are facing any issue.

Comment: I Have used above xpath still it is not working !! and no error , itself skipping that line

Comment: wired how it can be skipped.. does the code move to catch block after that line?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on  tag. 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("board-icons")).click()

Answer (score 0):

Does that element's visibility is  dependent on any action performed, if yes try using explicit wait. Apply explicit wait for that element to be clickable

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='board-icons'] ")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='board-icons'] ")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
element = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='board-icons']"));